# Apply xsl styling to a list view webpart in sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, xslt-list-view-web-part

I am working on a project in sharepoint 2010. I have a list view web part on a page. Currently it is just pulling and displaying data like a standard table view. Is there a way that I can edit the webpart to display the data using a custom xsl style. I have a custom xsl stylesheet and custom xsl, but I don't know how to make the list view reference this?

Comment: See https://paylord.wordpress.com/2012/09/28/cqwp-and-xslt-part-1/ But remember...learning XSLT in todays market is like learning to power your car by coal.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Danny, but the link you provided contains instructions for applying xsl to a content query webpart. I need to know how this can be done with a list view webpart, not a content query webpart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the ListView WebPart output in 2010, that is why I referred to the Content QUery WebPart

In SP2013 Microsoft added CSR (Client Side Rendering) JavaScript and the option to JSLink your JS file to a ListView webpart.

Note that all this Client Side goodness was disabled again (spring 2016) in SharePoint Online "Modern Experiences"

Till now (spring 2017) Microsoft does not allow any branding in "Modern Experiences", no CSS no JavaScript, no anything